# How to transfer value from a DropDownList to a property of a serialized model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm testing some concepts in ASP.NET MVC multisteps (Style Wizards) with a small application which allow me to records organizations in a database.

To make things easier, I've a class **OrganizationFormModelView** that contains an object of class **Organization** and a property called **ParentOrgList** of SelectList type. The only purpose of the selectList property is to be used by a DropDownList.

I've also serialize  **OrganizationFormModelView** to get the multisteps Wizard effect.

In my first view (or first step), I use a dropdownlist helper to assign a value to one of the the Organization's property called **ParentOrganization**, which draws data from the **ParentOrgList**.

```
...
<% = Html.DropDownList("Organization.ParentOrganization", Model.ParentOrgList)%>
...
```

The first time the page loads, I'm able to make a choice. And, my choice is reflected in my **object Model** all along the wizard' steps(see Visual studio in debugging mode).

But, when any time I'm redirected back to the first view (first step), I get the following error message:

***"The ViewData item with the key 'Organization.ParentOrganization' is of type 'System.String' but needs to be of type 'IEnumerable'."***

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you show us some more of your view and controller code? It sounds to me like the selected value of your DropDownList is somehow getting stored in the ViewData collection.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: you are right. I guess I need to look more closely to the ViewData and get back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considering carefully my code, I understand now what's going on. **OrganizationFormModelView** is the class that is being serialized, and here's its definition.

```
[Serializable]
public class OrganizationFormViewModel
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    [NonSerialized]
    public SelectList ParentOrgList = null;
    public OrganizationFormViewModel(Organization organization, SelectList cList)
    {
        Organization = organization ?? new Organization();
        ParentOrgList = pList;
    }
}
```

From that, I've concluded that, After each serialization process, **ParentOrgList** is set to null, so I need to find a way of re-assigning value to it. So, below is what I did:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrganization(string nextButton)
    {  
        //Omitted for brievety 
        if (formViewModel.ParentOrgList == null)
            formViewModel.ParentOrgList = repository.CommuneList;
        //Omitted for brievety 
    }
```

I also, modified the View so that, even if the value of the ParentOrgList is continuously re-assigned, but the DropDownList keeps the user's choice. So, I choose an Helper overload with default value.

```
...
<% = Html.DropDownList("Organization.ParentOrganization", Model.ParentOrgList, 
     Model.Organization.ParentOrganization)%>
...
```

Now, everything is working perfectly.

However, If someone knows how to proceed differently with the Serialization business, it'd be helpful to share.

Thanks